# How do i iterate multiple input::get into a foreach array to be stored into my database?

Tags: php, laravel

What I have created is a VueJS dynamic form that creates a new text input field on each button click. My question is:

How do i do this:

```
public function store(Request $req) {

$req->validate([
  'itemID' => 'required',
]);

foreach ($req->input('itemID') as $itemID) {
$sales = new Sales;
$sales->itemID = $itemID;
$sales->save();
}

return view('pages.displaySales');
}
```

For this,

```
  public function store(Request $req)
{
    $req->validate([
      'itemID' => 'required',
      'inventoryName' => 'required',
      'inventoryPrice' => 'required',
      'inventoryDesc' => 'required',
      'inventoryAmount' => 'required',
    ])



    $inventories = new Inventory;
    $inventories->itemID = Input::get('itemID');
    $inventories->inventoryName = Input::get('inventoryName');
    $inventories->inventoryPrice = Input::get('inventoryPrice');
    $inventories->inventoryDesc = Input::get('inventoryDesc');
    $inventories->inventoryAmount = Input::get('inventoryAmount');
    $inventories->save();

    return Input::all();
}
```

I'm very new to this and I have searched high and low with little results that I understand.

Comment: What's wrong with `$inventories = new Inventory($req->all()); $inventories->save();` ???

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or results that are wrong?

Comment: It only accepts input of the last form. For example, I click the add button and created 2 forms, when I submit, without the foreach loop, only the last form's inputs gets stored into my db.